# Custom Radio Control that fills color in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I want to make following UI in android xml. I googled but didn't find any good results.

I want to have may be set of circles that can be filled with color?

I will have array like this ["Red","Gray", "Yellow", ...] and want to render these color in the following control. And when I select any one of the color it should give it's value . Like when "Red" is selected it should give me "Red" value as selected.

Thank You.[image]

Comment: I don't understand why people down vote. If question is not good or need some edits then they can suggest. I think this is valid question and needs solution. May be the question topic doesn't explain well. I apologize on that. But please help me on this. Thank You.

Comment: Not sure how this is different than a lookup for your values [Red, Grey, etc.] or if you asking for a Custom View. Regardless from [What topic can I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) `asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic`

Comment: Hi @MorrisonChang, I have edited the question. Hope this clarifies the problem.

Comment: Not that much difference. Show what you've tried or what you've looked at with as much detail as possible. Right now it just sounds like you want someone to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i have done but it wont work like a radio button.

First add the colors you want in values/colors.xml file

```
<color name="red">#d50000</color>
<color name="green">#33691e</color>
<color name="blue">#304ffe</color>
```

Add this circle.xml drawable inside drawable folder. This drawable will be set as background for view(color button) at runtime.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="#000000"/>
    <size
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"/>
</shape>
```

In your layout file add a viewgroup (ex LinearLayout) which will contain the color buttons (will be added at runtime). Set id for the viewgroup for referencing.

Here's what i have done

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you have to add code which will add colored buttons with Onclick listeners.

Inside your activity class add an int array which will hold color resource values

```
int[] colors = {R.color.blue, R.color.red,R.color.green};
```

Add another int variable for storing the selected color value

```
int selected_color;
```

Now add this method in your activity class which will add color views(buttons) with OnClick listeners. When a color view is clicked it will store the color in selected_color variable.

```
public void addColorChoices() {
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    int hw = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 24, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(hw,hw);
    int m = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    lp.setMargins(m,m,m,m);

    View v;
    for(final int color: colors) {
        v = new View(this);
        v.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.circle));
        v.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(color)));
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
        v.setId(View.generateViewId());
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selected_color = color;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selected Color: " + getResources().getResourceEntryName(selected_color),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        container.addView(v);
    }
}
```

To add more color choices, just add the color in the array. Call this method from your activity's OnCreate() method.